# Send argument to custom field constraint

Tags: entities, 8

I have created custom field type with custom constraint defined and called successfully, the question is how to send the field settings to my constraint in the code block below.

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'custom_field_type' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "custom_field_type",
 *   label = @Translation("custom field type"),
 *   description = @Translation("custom field type"),
 *   default_widget = "number",
 *   default_formatter = "number_integer"
 * )
 */
class CustomFieldType extends IntegerItem {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function defaultFieldSettings() {
    return array(
      'type' => array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('type Validator'),
        '#default_value' => 'none',
        '#options' => [],
        '#description' => t('types.'),
      ),
        ) + parent::defaultFieldSettings();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fieldSettingsForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $type_options = array(
      'type1' => t('type1'),
      'type2' => t('type2'),
      'none' => t('type1 and type2'),
    );
    return array(
      'type' => array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('type Validator'),
        '#default_value' => $this->getSetting('type'),
        '#options' => $type_options,
        '#description' => t('types.'),
      ),
    );
  }

    /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $properties['value'] = DataDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('type'))
      ->addConstraint('CustomCheck')
      ->setRequired(TRUE);
    return $properties;
  }
}
```

How to send the field settings as arguments to the constraint as the validation only takes the field value as parameter.

```
/**
 * Validates the CustomCheckConstraint.
 */
class CustomCheckConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  /**
   * Validator 2.5 and upwards compatible execution context.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface
   */
  protected $context;
 public function validate($data, Constraint $constraint) {
//do custom check here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method addConstraint allows an optional array of options to be passed to the constraint plugin. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21DataDefinition.php/function/DataDefinition%3A%3AaddConstraint/8.2.x